# Transform data frame with set of intervals to set of discrete values

Tags: r

I have a data set where each record has an interval, and I'd like to have the same information but as a set of discrete values within that interval instead.

Example:
Input data frame

```
  start end val
1     2   4   a
2     2   5   b
3     1   3   c
```

Output data frame

```
  time val
1    2   a
2    3   a
3    4   a
4    2   b
5    3   b
6    4   b
7    5   b
8    1   c
9    2   c
10   3   c
```

What's a good way to accomplish that sort of transformation? Additionally, the val column could be multiple columns to repeat in the same pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
dd$time = Map(f = seq, dd$start, dd$end)
tidyr::unnest(dd[c("val", "time")])
#    val time
# 1    a    2
# 2    a    3
# 3    a    4
# 4    b    2
# 5    b    3
# 6    b    4
# 7    b    5
# 8    c    1
# 9    c    2
# 10   c    3
```

---

Using this sample data:

```
dd = read.table(text = "start end val
1     2   4   a
2     2   5   b
3     1   3   c", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(time = seq(start, end)), by = val][]
#    val time
# 1:   a    2
# 2:   a    3
# 3:   a    4
# 4:   b    2
# 5:   b    3
# 6:   b    4
# 7:   b    5
# 8:   c    1
# 9:   c    2
#10:   c    3
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(start = c(2L, 2L, 1L), end = c(4L, 5L, 3L), val = c("a", 
"b", "c")), .Names = c("start", "end", "val"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3"))
```